# Do these two parts in Hurley's logic book introduce natural deduction or different deductive systems?

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

In Hurley's An Concise Introduction to Logic

- [Section 6.6 Arguments Forms and Fallacies](https://books.google.com/books?id=qGBQAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT400&pg=PT396#v=onepage&q&f=false) introduces several valid argument forms: modus ponens, disjuctive syllogism, ...
- [Ch 7: Natural Deduction in Propositional Logic](https://books.google.com/books?id=qGBQAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT400&pg=PT409#v=onepage&q&f=false) introduces   rules of inference which "[should be familiar from Section 6.6](https://books.google.com/books?id=qGBQAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT400&pg=PT410#v=onepage&q&f=false)".

Does Section 6.6 also introduces natural deduction, or a different deductive system (like Hilbert deduction)?

If both  Section 6.6 and Chapter 7 introduce natural deduction, what is the difference between them? (Apart from subjective writing plan of the author.)

Thanks.

Comment: No significant difference... IMO, Hurley's system is quite "approximate" compared to "standard" [Natural Deduction](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/). In Ch.6 the author state several valid inference schema; between them, in Ch.7 some are chosen as basic.